# Resampling Sentinel-2 images

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, resolution, resampling

I want to change Band-11 (SWIR Bands) of Sentinel-2 to 10m resolution. I found resampling process used for it. Doesn't it affect the spectral characteristics for processing further???

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is go from fine spatial resolution (10-m) to coarser spatial resolution (20-m) but it is not best practice to resample the other way. It introduces error. When using a panchromatic band, I believe going from coarse to fine is permitted. However Sentinel-2 does not have a panchromatic band.